# Vscode cant find haxe

Tags: android

So here is the thing, I am having problem with visual studio code. I also tried flashdevelop. At first it was going great. But later it started given errors when try to open it and it wont open. So i downloaded visual studio code. The first problem i encountered is vscode could not find my haxe and openfl. I ran lime setup android, but when ever i try to debug, it keeps telling me to setup android. So i tried to figure it out my self but things just got worst. When ever i run anything on my cmd it shows me errors like : lime is not recognized as an internal or external code. I have learnt seven different languages, but haxeflixel seems to be the simplest, but very frustrating to install.

I need your help please!.

Comment: Can you post the exact error you are currently experiencing?

Comment: The real problem is that i cant test on my android. I have successfully setup android in the cmd but when try to test it i get this error.

Comment: You need to run "lime setup android" in the command prompt

Comment: it started working after i setup lime. But when compiling for android it stops at Link: libApplicationv7. so. When i went into my export file i actually saw that file. But what will i use it for and why is it stopping there.